# Simulating an 'Any' type in F#

Tags: f#

I'd like to create a type with a definition a bit like this:

```
type LeftRight<'left, 'right> = {
    Left : 'left list
    Right : 'right list
    }
```

and a couple of functions:

```
let makeLeft xs = { Left = xs; Right = [] }

let makeRight ys = { Left = []; Right = ys }
```

and I'd like to provide a 'combiner' function:

```
let combine l r = { Left = l.Left @ r.Left; Right = l.Right @ r.Right }
```

When I try and make something, I (obviously!) get issues as my value is generic:

```
let aaa = makeLeft [1;2;3]
// Value restriction. The value 'aaa' has been inferred to have generic type
// val aaa : LeftRight<int,'_a>
```

If I combine a left and a right, type inference kicks in and everything's A-OK:

```
let bbb = makeRight [1.0;2.0;3.0]
let comb = combine aaa bbb // LeftRight<int, float>
```

but I want to use one with only lefts on its own. I tried creating an 'Any' type:

```
type Any = Any
```

and explicitly specified the types on makeLeft and makeRight:

```
let makeLeft xs : LeftRight<_, Any> = { Left = xs; Right = [] }

let makeRight ys : LeftRight<Any, _> = { Left = []; Right = ys }
```

which makes the value definitions happy, but makes the combine function sad:

```
let combined = combine aaa bbb
// Type mismatch. Expecting a
//     LeftRight<int,Any>    
// but given a
//     LeftRight<Any,float>    
// The type 'int' does not match the type 'Any'
```

I feel like there's probably a way around this with loads of voodoo with .Net's overloading of function calls, but I can't make it work. Has anyone tried this before/have any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value restriction is not a problem in this case, you need the result of `makeLeft` or `makeRight` be generic if you ever hope to use them generically further down the line.

In F# (and OCaml), generic syntactic values must be explicitly marked as such, with full type annotations.  Indeed, the compiler reports this:

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'aaa' has been inferred to
>   have generic type
>       val aaa : LeftRight     Either define 'aaa' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do
>   not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Without going into too much detail*, this is to avoid issues that can occur when combining polymorphism and side effects.  The downside is that it does reject some perfectly safe code as a result.

So, the solution is simple, we make these values explicitly generic:

```
let aaa<'a> : LeftRight<int,'a> = makeLeft [1;2;3]

let bbb<'a> : LeftRight<'a, float> = makeRight [1.0;2.0;3.0]
```

Putting them together in FSI:

```
let comb = combine aaa bbb;;;
```

> ```
> val comb : LeftRight<int,float> = {Left = [1; 2; 3];
>                                Right = [1.0; 2.0; 3.0];}
> ```

Note that if you combine  without intermediate let bindings, you no longer have a generic value and the proper type can be inferred by the compiler:

```
combine (makeLeft [1;2;3]) (makeRight [1.0;2.0;3.0]);;
```

> ```
> val it : LeftRight<int,float> = {Left = [1; 2; 3];
>                                  Right = [1.0; 2.0; 3.0];}
> ```

---

*For more detail, check out [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/).

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know you were able to place generic arguments on values. This fixes it without having to mess with 'Any' types all over the place!

Comment: That said, it seems this gets a bit weird when you have a type constraint - `let aaa<'a when 'a : comparison> = ...` could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.

Comment: @MattKemp I don't see any problem with doing that.  What are you putting on the right hand side?

Comment: I actually found that in my (more complicated) case it was over-determining the type, and less annotation was better. Swapping `let left<'a when 'a : comparison> : LeftRight<_, 'a> = makeLeft [1;2;3]` for just `let left<'a> = makeLeft[1;2;3]` -makes it happy-, though it does appear that `'a` gets type-inferred to `System.IComparable`.